I need to store references to a single-ownership piece of data to be able to later mutate the data
I have a Vec of Foos which represent some data, which I think is arbitrary for the purposes of this question. At some point in time, I want to modify some of the Foos accoding to a schedule I can calculate at the start, but which might change later.
I am keeping track of this schedule by using a BinaryHeap of DecayEvents, where each DecayEvent stores a reference to the Foo that is going to mutate/decay, and the time when it will do so. In this way, I can schedule the mutations, and work out which one should be mutating by pop()ing from the BinaryHeap, and then obtaining the reference to the Foo that will decay. Crucially, my problem is working out how to store this reference so that I can modify it later, even if the same Foo might decay twice, meaning that I would have to store multiple mutable references.
The Foos should be totally owned, as far as I can work out, by the Vec that is storing them. Having read the Rust Book page on Rc and shared ownership, I can see that

if we knew which part would finish last, we could just make that part the data’s owner, and the normal ownership rules enforced at compile time would take effect.

I know that the Foos should live as long as the Vec they are in, which should live to the end of my simulation/main() in this case. So, single ownership seems appropriate.
However, I am then unsure how to handle keeping track of the references to the Foos. If I didn't need to mutate them, this would be simple: I could just use &'a Foo as the reference embedded in the DecayEvent struct. In this case, I can't later mutate the Foos, which is a problem.
Currently, I am achieving mutation by using std::Cell::RefCell, like below:
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: char,
}

impl Foo {
    fn mutate(&mut self, new_bar: char) {
        self.bar = new_bar
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DecayEvent<'a> {
    foo: RefMut<'a, Foo>,
    time: u64,
}

impl PartialEq for DecayEvent<'_> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.time == other.time
    }
}

impl Eq for DecayEvent<'_> {}

impl PartialOrd for DecayEvent<'_> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
        self.time.partial_cmp(&other.time)
    }
}

impl Ord for DecayEvent<'_> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        self.time.cmp(&other.time)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foos: Vec<RefCell<Foo>> = Vec::new();
    for c in "ABCDEF".chars() {
        foos.push(RefCell::new(Foo { bar: c }))
    }

    let mut decays: BinaryHeap<DecayEvent> = BinaryHeap::new();
    for (i, foo) in foos.iter().enumerate() {
        decays.push(DecayEvent {
            foo: foo.borrow_mut(),
            time: i as u64,
        })
    }

    println!("{:?}", decays.pop());
    println!("{:?}", decays.pop());

    let decay = decays.pop().unwrap();
    let mut mut_foo = decay.foo;

    println!("{:?}", mut_foo);
    mut_foo.mutate('X');
    println!("{:?}", mut_foo);

    /*If I uncomment the block below, then the thread will panic
    when it tries to create a second mutable reference to the Foo. */

    // for (i, foo) in foos.iter().enumerate() {
    //     decays.push(DecayEvent {
    //         foo: foo.borrow_mut(),
    //         time: i as u64 + 10,
    //     })
    // }

    // println!("{:?}", decays.pop());
    // println!("{:?}", decays.pop());

    // let decay = decays.pop().unwrap();
    // let mut mut_foo = decay.foo;

    // println!("{:?}", mut_foo);
    // mut_foo.mutate('Y');
    // println!("{:?}", mut_foo);
}

I set up a playground permalink, too. The problem is, I can't then store multiple mutable references to the Foos within my queue, as per the Rust borrowing rules: as set out in my code, I get a runtime panic.
I understand this, and I have looked through the related SO answers I could find, including these:

Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types
How to represent shared mutable state?

However, the examples provided have a mutable borrow being performed directly on the original, owned piece of data, where as I need to somehow store the mutable references for later use in this queue.
Are there any std types or structures that would let me basically uncomment the bottom lines of my code?
To maybe clarify this further, an idea that occurred to me was to use the list indices of the Foos in the Vec as a way of keeping track of who would decay when, and then using the list indices to obtain the original data and hence make the necessary modification. However, this would mean that I would be totally reliant on the list indexing, which I wanted to avoid, partially to see if this could be achieved using the Rust borrowing rules.

A common workaround is to avoid lifetimes entirely by using some other way to indicate which object to "reference", by using their index for example. When mutating, your decay event can be given a mutable reference to the foos, and determine for itself which one to mutate. Is that sufficient for your use-case?

Or trying a different angle, you are encountering the conflict because you are acquiring exclusivity up-front. If you instead only reference the refcell (i.e. foo: &'a RefCell<Foo>), then you don't require exclusivity until you actually need it (a modifying function would do .borrow_mut() then, do its thing, and release the mutable borrow at the end).

@kmdreko To be honest, for the original use case, I think that would work, I could use the indices because of the vec. However, I wanted to understand how to generalise this further: what about if the order of the foos might change, or if some might even be added or destroyed? I grant that this might make keeping track of them altogether much more difficult, but I feel like there should be a way to achieve this with references, especially because this is what the indices are effectively doing: providing me a way to reference the foos as many times as I like such that I can later modify them.

@kmdreko in reply to your second comment: I think this would work, I will try it and let you know where it gets me! EDIT: This was exactly what I needed, thanks!

If the order of them may change or the Vec might grow, the references to them will be invalidated as they'll change locations in memory. &RefCell<Foo> will also not work in this case.

Hi, can you explain what you mean by this, please? Does this mean that if I try to mutate the Vec then my code is going to refuse to compile, or is it actually that my references will start pointing to the wrong elements in the Vec. Wouldn't this be unsafe, then?

There are a few options to get around this issue. For additional reference this is contemplated in ECS design for games as well. Here are a few options:
&mut T
You could actually make this work since you are never editing the Vec. To do this the Vec would store Ts directly. You add all the items to the Vec first, then create the list of decay events either with slice::split_at_mut or slice::get_many_mut on nightly.
You would be limited to a single decay event per item and wouldn't be able to change the Vec's contents. This is because if you push or resize the Vec then it may get reallocated. This results in the references becoming invalid (a safety issue) since all the items move to the new allocation. Removing items also (maybe) results in invalid pointers. You'd face the same problem in C++ but the compiler wouldn't stop you.
RefCell
RefCells are similar to running the borrow checker at run time. I've found that the only time they are useful is when input to a program can be dynamically duplicated while also needing to be mutated and you are limited to a single thread (this is very niche). References to RefCells in structs is almost always bad.
This strategy requires your storage to be Vec<RefCell<T>>. Your decay events would store references to individual RefCells.
This eliminates the only one decay event per item requirement from above but still suffers from being unable to add/remove to/from the Vec.
Indexes
This strategy is what you discussed later in your post, storing a Vec<T> and indexes in the decay events. You identified some of the issues like when mutating the Vec needing to maintain the indexes to point to the correct value.
This will only work with an append only list. Removals would be supported by marking the removed values with tombstones but memory could never be recovered without updating all indexes.
Generations
This strategy is very similar to how ECSs work in games. Here's some data structures:
enum Generation<T>{
  Filled{
    value: T,
    generation: usize,
   },
  Empty{
    generation: usize,
  },
}

type Storage<T> = Vec<Generation<T>>;

struct DecayEvent<T> {
  generation: usize,
  index: usize,
  // ...
}

Each index is augmented with a generation.

On access, if the slot is filled and the generation is the same then access it, otherwise it was deleted.
Adds are supported by finding the first empty slot (adding a new one if none) and incrementing its generation. By incrementing the generation if an index to the slot is used again it will know that the value it originally referenced was removed and replaced.
Removes just mark the slot as empty. Could also do some memory cleanup here.

This can further be optimized by making the generations NonZeroUsize so rust can do niche optimization on the enum.
I always encourage writing these things out for yourself, if you don't want to do that there are a few libraries that offer this functionality:

slotmap: built for exactly this case. Has multiple variants with different tradeoffs for access time, iteration time, and memory usage.
bevy_ecs: A full ECS implementation in Rust. A heavy dependency but I've found it to be a super useful pattern.

Conclusion
In case you can't tell I suggest you use the generations pattern. It's much better than references because you both don't have to deal with lifetimes but also can freely design your program to do whatever you want. If you want to multithread it I'd suggest tossing it onto a worker thread. If you need to multithread tasks either lock each index or venture into ECS territory which is inherently multithread-able.

Hey! Thanks for the detail in this reply. I am not sure I 100% correctly understand, so loosely: I would store my Foos as part of your defined Storage so as the Value<T> enum variant. Then, my DecayEvents can safely reference back to the Storage using this generation pattern, and if I need to add/remove Foos this becomes possible and easy due to the semantics introduced, making it superior to just using the indices. Is that about right?

@whatf0xx Yes, take a look at slotmap too for some examples
